# Crashing at point where there is seemingly no error

Tags: objective-c, struct, objective-c++

I've just whittled out loads of erros and now my code compiles fine, however it always crashes in the createEntity method i made. there is seemingly nothing wrong with it, but could someone help me anyway? Anything to suggest?

```
 -(void)createEntityWithX:(int)newEntityX andY:(int)newEntityY withType:(int)newEntityType withWidth:(int)newEntityWidth andLength:(int)newEntityLength atSpeed:(int)newEntitySpeed
{
  Entity tmpEntity;
  tmpEntity.entityX = newEntityX;
  tmpEntity.entityY = newEntityY;
  tmpEntity.entityLength = newEntityLength;
  tmpEntity.entityWidth = newEntityWidth;
  tmpEntity.entityType = newEntityType;
  tmpEntity.entitySpeed = newEntitySpeed;

  int arrayAmount = [entityArray count];
  NSValue *tmp = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&tmpEntity objCType:@encode(struct Entity)];

  [entityArray insertObject:tmp atIndex:arrayAmount];

  [tmp release];
}
```

Comment: have you debugged to see which line is causing trouble?

Comment: int arrayAmount = [entityArray count];
  NSValue *tmp = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&tmpEntity objCType:@encode(struct Entity)];

  [entityArray insertObject:tmp atIndex:arrayAmount]; one of these... its compiling fine but crashing when this method is called

Comment: and what is the crash message?

Comment: I dont have one because i cant debug on a computer, its just whenever this method is called... Is there any way you can see what the error is likely to be from that?

Comment: When posting asking for help with a crash, please include the error message. In this case that would either be «'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI insertObject:atIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance» or «uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index beyond bounds for empty array»

Comment: What do you mean you can't debug on a computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One or both of two things is wrong here. It's possible that `entityArray` is not an `NSMutableArray`, but an `NSArray`, in which case you're getting an "unrecognized selector" error.

After that's fixed, you need to fix your indexing. You can't *insert* an object into an `NSMutableArray` at the index corresponding to its `count`, because the last valid index for insertion is `count-1`. You should use `addObject:` to put something at the end of the array:

```
NSValue *tmp = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&tmpEntity objCType:@encode(struct Entity)];

[entityArray addObject:tmp];
```

Comment: I thought that because its base-0, item 10 would be at index 9, so count would return 10 anyway?

Comment: Yes, and the last valid index for insertion is 9.